# Accessing data in a nested structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

Okay so I've found a better way of accessing my files but I'm still a bit stuck.

My code so far:

```
clc % clear window
clear %clear workspace

numfiles = 21;
data = cell(1, numfiles);

obsdata = dir('*.mat'); 
numfiles = length(obsdata);
data = cell(1, numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles 
  data{k} = load(obsdata(k).name); 
end
```

This sorts my data out.
There are 21 cells that contains the J6 - files as shown (the list of the files can be seen on the left):
[image: Files]
Clicking each cell brings me to a structure:
[image: Structure]
Each of which contains data that I want to access.

I'm unsure as to how to go about writing my code so that I can store the data in the last part into two arrays (wavelength and intensity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used `deal` to copy out each of the `obsdata.name`'s into a cell array called `names`. (It's probably a poor choice of name for a variable since you already have one called `name`, but anyway...)

```
obsdata = dir('*.mat'); 
numfiles = length(obsdata);
data = cell(1, numfiles);
names = cell(1,numfiles);
names = cell(1,numfiles);
[names{:}] = deal(obsdata.name);
for k = 1:numfiles
  data{k} = load(names{k}) 
end
```

Comment: this gives me a names file with the list of all the names.. However it doesn't give me access to store the files that within each of the J6 files. Apologies if the answer seems obvious but I'm still trying to understand how it works

Comment: I think you'll have to give a clear example of what your data actually is. As it is I'm just guessing. What are the contents of your `.mat` files?

Answer (score 0):

It'd help to hear a little bit more about how you want to store the data, but generally the work will be done inside the loop you use to load the files. A good starting point might be to get the data out of structs and into cell arrays:

```
for k = 1:numfiles 
  data{k} = struct2cell(load(obsdata(k).name)); 
end
```

I believe (it's been a while, and I don't have access to matlab anymore) that each of the 21 cells will now contain a cell array, storing the matrices you're interested in. Perhaps this is enough? From this point I think you can access data like this:

```
data{file_num}{struct_field_num}(x,y)
```

where `x` and `y` are the indices within the matrices that used to be stored as fields in a struct.

If you want to concatenate each of these matrices so that you get 21 cells, each with a single mx2 matrix, you can modify the loop:

```
for k = 1:numfiles 
  tmp = load(obsdata(k).name); 
  data{k} = vertcat(tmp{:});
end
```

With more information about how you want to structure the data we can refine the answer.

Comment: this is semi working! yaaay! but Question..
I have a for loop that looks like this : 
for n = 56:59
     F=getfield((data{1,1}{1,1}),sprintf('order_%d',n));
 end
 now.. this only gets the data from {1,1}, but I want it to access 1:(each of the 21 cells). How do I get it to do that? I'm not access all of the data at the moment.. the code is processing a few files so I'm hoping that solving this would work

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with that loop actually -- I need a bit more context. But has your original question been answered? If so, you could mark it as answered and post a new one.